# WooCommerce how to remove linebreaks generated by the default products CSV export

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, export, product

I'm in a project, using the default CSV Import/Export tool by wordpress to manage the products of an online store. Since it's known restrictions in certain areas (compatibility with plugins), I can't however solely rely on that tool to have a CSV-only product base. Certain changes want be done directly in WP GUI as well.

Problems start when I want to improve product descriptions by adding line breaks and paragraphs to make things more human readable: When I import a correctly formatted CSV, I can export it just as perfectly formatted until I modify something in the product directly via GUI. It doesn't even necessarily need to be a change in the description. Changing any other field screws up my next CSV export just as well: Line breaks (`<br>`) and paragraphs (`<p>`) are for whatever reason replaced by a line break followed by "\n". Product-exports are not usable anymore and force me to preformat any export before usage, with Notepad++, which is beyond annoying.

Is the default import-export tool really that bad up to this day or am I missing something very basic to avoid this issue? Is there any way of managing product import and exports with ease? The version used in this project is Wordpress 6.2.

Thank you in advance,

Alan

Comment: I don't think that you can retrieve the original data once you edited it with WP.

Comment: I don't need the original data. The export of the current products is what I'm looking for (this function basically already exists in Woocommerce, but it's cluttered with NewLines that screw up the exported CSV.

Comment: Without any sample lines of the original/imported, modified/exported and modified/expected CSVs, it's difficult to understand what you mean by "perfectly formatted". Do you want the `<br>` and `<p>` to appear in the exported CSV?

Answer (score 4):

> *"Linebreaks `<br>` and paragraphs `<p>` tags are, for whatever reason, replaced by a line break followed by `\n`. Product-exports are not usable anymore*

The reason is a `protected function called "filter_description_field"` in the [`class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php#L590-L603).

Here's the function provided by woocommerce that's causing this behavior!

```php
/**
 * Filter description field for export.
 * Convert newlines to '\n'.
 *
 * @param string $description Product description text to filter.
 *
 * @since  3.5.4
 * @return string
*/
protected function filter_description_field( $description ) {
  $description = str_replace( '\n', "\\\\n", $description );
  $description = str_replace( "\n", '\n', $description );
  return $description;
}
```

[And it's being called for both `description` and `short_description` fields](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php#L248-L250).

> **`p` tag:**
> [By default, browsers separate paragraphs with a single blank line.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p#styling_paragraphs)

> **`br` tag:**
> [The `br` HTML element produces a line break in text (carriage-return).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

So if I add a `p` tag and/or a `br` tag to the `short description` field, it would be something like this:

[image]

Some `csv` parsers wouldn't handle `\n` the way you want and some would! For example, this is a screenshot from `Microsoft Excel` which, in this case, didn't break into a new cell and shows the data correctly:

[image]

But if I open up the same `csv` file with the `Windows Notepad`, it will break into a new line and mess up the formatting of the data, here's a screenshot:

[image]

---

> *"force me to pre-format any export before usage with Notepad++, which is beyond annoying."*

Fortunately, Woocommerce has provided us with a filter hook called [`woocommerce_product_export_row_data`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php#L268) which let us automate this process. So you don't have to manually manipulate your `description` and `short_description` fields before exporting!

We could use either `regular expressions` or `string manipulation techniques` to modify the `\n` added by Woocommerce as a default behavior!

---

#### 1- Using [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)  function and [`woocommerce_product_export_row_data`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php#L268) filter hook:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_export_row_data', 'your_theme_custom_export_data', 2, 999);

function your_theme_custom_export_data($row, $product)
{
    foreach ($row as $row_name => $row_value)
    {
        $row_name = strstr($row_name, ':') ? current(explode(':', $row_name)) : $row_name;

        if ('description' === $row_name || 'short_description' === $row_name)
        {
            $row[$row_name] = str_replace('\n', '', $row_value);
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

---

#### 2- Using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function and [`woocommerce_product_export_row_data`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php#L268) filter hook:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_export_row_data', 'your_theme_custom_export_data', 2, 999);

function your_theme_custom_export_data($row, $product)
{
    foreach ($row as $row_name => $row_value)
    {
        $row_name = strstr($row_name, ':') ? current(explode(':', $row_name)) : $row_name;

        if ('description' === $row_name || 'short_description' === $row_name)
        {
            $row[$row_name] = preg_replace('/\\\\n+/', '', $row_value);
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

---

Here's a screenshot after removing/replacing line breaks `\n`:

[image]

[image]

---

**Note:**

- I've used `999` priority, which let your function run after `woocommerce exporter class` has modified your data and right before it generates a `csv` file. Feel free to change the priority number and/or regular expression to meet your needs.
- Since we're using a `filter hook`, the data won't change in your db! So the description fields remain intact on the admin panel of your woocommerce store, which means they are still "human readable"!

[image]

---

This answer has been tested and works fine! The snippets above would go to the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

Comment: OP didn't specify what final result he's looking for after exporting the CSV, but nice finding +1